# Calculate date lag

Tags: r, date

I have a dataframe with this shape:

```
 date       date_lag test_date 
  <date>        <dbl> <date>    
1 2018-12-01       NA 2018-12-01
2 2019-03-01       90 2019-03-01
3 2019-05-01       61 2019-03-01
4 2020-03-10      314 2020-03-10
5 2020-03-16        6 2020-03-10
6 2020-03-23        7 2020-03-16
7 2020-03-24        1 2020-03-23
```

In order to create `date_lag` & `test_date`, I applied this code:

```
lag <- lag %>%
  mutate(date_lag = as.numeric(date - lag(date), units="days")) %>%
  mutate(test_date = case_when(
    is.na(date_lag) ~ date,
    date_lag < 69 ~ date-date_lag,
    TRUE ~ date))
```

If dates are less than 69 days apart, I want them to have the same date. The problem with my code is that if you see column 6, I don't want it to have the date of column 5 but the date of column 4 because the date_lag is still less than 69 days apart from the previous column, meaning that my desired data will look like:

```
 date       date_lag test_date 
  <date>        <dbl> <date>    
1 2018-12-01       NA 2018-12-01
2 2019-03-01       90 2019-03-01
3 2019-05-01       61 2019-03-01
4 2020-03-10      314 2020-03-10
5 2020-03-16        6 2020-03-10
6 2020-03-23        7 2020-03-10
7 2020-03-24        1 2020-03-10
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the dates. For each, compute the difference with all other dates. Using these differences, find the earliest date that's fewer than 69 days before the index date.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

# example data
date_df <- tibble(
  date = ymd("2018-12-01", "2019-03-01", "2019-05-01", "2020-03-10", 
             "2020-03-16", "2020-03-23", "2020-03-24")
)

earliest_within <- function(dates, n) {
  map(dates, ~ min(dates[.x - dates < n])) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as_date()
}

date_df %>%
  mutate(test_date = earliest_within(date, 69))

#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>   date       test_date 
#>   <date>     <date>    
#> 1 2018-12-01 2018-12-01
#> 2 2019-03-01 2019-03-01
#> 3 2019-05-01 2019-03-01
#> 4 2020-03-10 2020-03-10
#> 5 2020-03-16 2020-03-10
#> 6 2020-03-23 2020-03-10
#> 7 2020-03-24 2020-03-10
```

Comment: What if I want to apply the map function grouping by another variable, how a group_by() can be included?

Comment: I edited my answer and put everything in a function to better accommodate a dplyr workflow — including grouped operations. So you can do `date_df %>% group_by(group_var) %>% mutate(test_date = earliest_within(date, 69))`.

Answer (score 1):

*data.table* option, which might work well for bigger datasets:

```
library(data.table)
dat[, test_date := dat[
          dat[, .(date, datem69 = date-69)],
          on=.(date<=date, date>=datem69), x.date, mult="first"]
    ]
##         date  test_date
##1: 2018-12-01 2018-12-01
##2: 2019-03-01 2019-03-01
##3: 2019-05-01 2019-03-01
##4: 2020-03-10 2020-03-10
##5: 2020-03-16 2020-03-10
##6: 2020-03-23 2020-03-10
##7: 2020-03-24 2020-03-10
```

Where `dat` was:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("date
2018-12-01
2019-03-01
2019-05-01
2020-03-10
2020-03-16
2020-03-23
2020-03-24")
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `shift()` function inside the `ifelse` and got your desired output. It goes up specified amount of rows and grabs the value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
lag <- lag %>% 
    mutate(
        test_date=ifelse(date_lag > 68 | is.na(date_lag),
                         date,
                         shift(date,1))
    )
lag

        date date_lag  test_date
1 2018-12-01       NA 2018-12-01
2 2019-03-01       90 2019-03-01
3 2019-05-01       61 2019-03-01
4 2020-03-10      314 2020-03-10
5 2020-03-16        6 2020-03-10
6 2020-03-23        7 2020-03-16
7 2020-03-24        1 2020-03-23
```